# How to insertmany from a cursor using Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

I am interested in using a cursor to duplicate a database from one mongod to another. I want to limit the amount of insert requests sent so instead of inserting each document in the cursor individually I want to do an insert_many of each cursor batch.

Is there a way to do this in pymongo/python?

I have tried converting the cursor to a list and then calling insert_many and this works, but if the collection is over the amount of ram that I have then it won't work.

Any ideas on how to grab a batch from a cursor and convert it to a list would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this has been my "slice/batch" solution and it has been much more effective than individually iterating each document from the cursor:

- Keep note of the id field last document you have grabbed
- Open a cursor with the query "Greater than _id of last doc" and with a limit of 
  whatever your batch_size is
- Now you should have a cursor with your desired number of documents in a batch
- Make this cursor into a python list by doing list(cursor)
- Insert_many on this list
- Update last grabbed, and delete the list to free up ram

You can adjust your batch size to accommodate your RAM limitations. This is a pretty good solution because it reduces the bottleneck of cursor iteration, and also doesn't take too much ram as you are constantly deleting the batches as you go on.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but I had the same issue very recently. I found lots of solutions, none of them satisfactory for my specific case.

In your case, does it **have** to be with python/pymongo and with a cursor? If so there is currently no way to do this, but I spent a good amount of time digging through the [pymongo source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/ff3c18ffbc05f0a39874faf25b896c71ff4ad009/pymongo/collection.py#L470) to confirm and I think I can use some of their lower level APIs to accomplish this. Will let you know when I do.